# HTML/CSS - Div overlay CSS Firefox for Android vs Firefox for iOS differences

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I have a slide out menu on my webpage. In Firefox for iOS, it works and looks normal.

In Firefox for Android, it doesn't work.

Why is the behavior in Firefox for Android different? How do I correct it so it looks like iOS?

Here is the iOS screenshot first and the Android screenshot second. Code is below the screenshots.

[image]

[image]

Here is the HTML and CSS of the menu

```
'meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"'

<div id="slideOutMenu">
    <span>X</span>
    <span>Home</span>
    <span>Preferences</span>
    <span>About</span>
    <span>Legal</span>
    <span>Contact</span>
</div>

#slideOutMenu {
    right: 0 !important;
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) !important;
    transition: transform .381s ease-in-out 0s !important;
    width: 221px;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: auto;
    z-index: 200;
    background: #3f3f3f;
    box-shadow: -1px 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.29034);
    z-index: 1111;
    overflow-y: auto;
    min-height: 100vh;
    min-height: -webkit-fill-available;
}
```

Comment: Firefox for iOS uses WebKit, while the Android one uses Gecko. They are two different rendering engines which is why it's so different. My hunch is that `-webkit-fill-available` may be overriding the 100vh but is also not a valid value in Gecko.

Comment: Ok very interesting and super helpful. What should I use for Gecko then to make the height of the slide out menu fill 100% of the screen?

Comment: 100vh is 100% of the viewport height. I don't know why you have the other -webkit-fill-available entry. Is there any particular reason for that? You could just remove that line.

Comment: I added -webkit-fill-available to fix a problem with Safari for iOS mobile. 100vh doesn't work in Safari and causes problems.

Comment: I'll try removing the min-height property entirely

Comment: Removing min-height partially fixes it. I think I need to find Gecko's version of -webkit-fill-available

Comment: Would min-height: -moz-available; do the trick?

Comment: Adding min-height: -moz-available; fixed it. Thanks for explaining the difference between Gecko and Webkit! If you post min-height: -moz-available; as the answer I will give you credit

Answer (score 0):

Adding `min-height: -moz-available;` fixed it.